# how to cast java.io.File to com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File

Tags: java, file, design-patterns, file-upload, casting

I am working in liferay
I have this function:

```
public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

public void abc(ActionRequest arq,ActionResponse ars) throws Exception {
    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(arq);
    FileUploader fileUp = new FileUploaderImpl();
    fileUp.setFid(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment("FileUploader.class"));
    File file = (File) uploadRequest.getFile("file");   
    byte[] bytes = FileUtil.getBytes(file);
    fileUp.setContent(Base64.objectToString(bytes));
    FileUploaderLocalServiceUtil.addFileUploader(fileUp);
}
}
```

Where File is of com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File;
I am trying to upload image using the above function. I get the UI to upload the image and when I click submit I get the following error:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-37][render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File
at com.test.image.test.NewPortlet.abc(NewPortlet.java:25)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:153)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:250)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:80)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:220)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:579)
```

What should I do to cast java.io.File to com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast `java.io.File` to `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File`, because `java.io.File` does not implement the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File` interface.

Remember that you can only cast A to B when A **is-a** B.

Comment: Cameron Skinner: Thanks for the prompt reply. I removed all the casts and it works as of now..

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is that you cant ... 'cos `java.io.File` is not a subclass of the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File` interface.

---

But the real answer is that you probably shouldn't be trying to the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.File` interface at all.  From what I can make out, it is a interface for some kind of utils class ... which doesn't have any obvious implementation classes.  (Frankly, I can't figure out why this interface exists at all!)

In fact, I *think* you should be doing this:

```
java.io.File file = ...
byte[] bytes = com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil.getBytes(file);
```

or alternatively:

```
java.io.File file = ...
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil fu = 
            new com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil();
byte[] bytes = fu.getBytes(file);
```

(I've used fully qualified names for illustration purposes only ...)

This is based on the Liferay 5.1 javadocs and source code that I found here.  YMMV.